# Mixed apostrophes in “unclear what you’re asking” description

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, close-reasons, close-dialog

I stumbled across the following sentence in the description of “unclear what you’re asking” close reason:

```
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
```

The first `it's` as well as the `you're` uses the typewriter or vertical apostrophe (U+0027 `'`) while the second `it’s` shows the [typographic or curly apostrophe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe#Typographic_form) (U+2019 `’`)<sub>, which is the preferred character to use for apostrophe according to [the Unicode standard](https://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/ch06.pdf).</sub>

This applies to the description on closed questions as well as the close dialog. On https://askubuntu.com/help/closed-questions on the other hand only typewriter apostrophes are used.

As a typography enthusiast I'd opt for the curly apostrophe, but `I’m` fine with the alternative as well – **as long as `it’s` consistent!**

What's the difference you may ask. Well, try `echo it’s` as opposed to `echo it's` in your favorite shell once…

Comment: How does one even write that apostrophe? I just have the single quote.

Comment: @TheWanderer It’s `AltGr+Shift+N`.

Comment: That's my tilde. The closest I have is `´`, which is an accent and not the same thing.

Comment: Found it. It's `AltGr+}` for me. `’`

Comment: @TheWanderer Now you just need to find `‘`, `“` and `”` and you’re able to quote beautifully.

Comment: `‘` `”` `”` I gotchu. Just combos of Shift and the other bracket.

Comment: What if you don't have `AltGR`?

Comment: @ubashu Then you just define a different shortcut I guess. :)

Comment: If you don't have any key that produces that character, just press Ctrl+Shift+U2019

Comment: This is hilarious... It's been this way for five years, and I just never noticed because they look the same in the usual font.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why it's this way, but that’s how someone wrote them. I blame Google Docs.

Changing it now means forcing the International sites to re-translate the entire close reason, so... Doesn't seem like a good use of their time. But if we ever make a substantive edit to that close reason, we'll definitely mess with apostrophes some more.

tl’dr: Unicode ruins everything.